# NGX-MASK Masking

Tags: angular, masking, ngx-mask

I am using ngx-mask to implement masking in my angular application.
https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask.

My requirement is whenever user types alphabets either in small case or upper case, mask should convert all chars in to uppercase. Currently masking is restricting me not to enter lower case chars if I have upper case mask and vice versa.

Requirement:
Mask - UUU-LLL-UUU
user types - STACkover
should be converted to - STA-cko-VER

How to change the default behaviour, so that user can type lower or upper case and later apply mask.